# Using Date as an index in IndexedDb and sorting with it

Tags: indexeddb

I'm currently using a `guid` as a keypath in my object store.

I'd like to add an index - `created` - that I can then use to get the newest entry.  I have added the index: 
[image]

This is how I was originally attempting to get the newest entry (via `getNewest`) but it was not working as expected:

```
const latestMediaRequest = store.getAll();
latestMediaRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
      const allData = event.target.result;
      const targetEntry = allData[allData.length - 1];  // nope               
}
```

This is how I'm currently adding entries (working):

```
 const request = database.transaction(storeName, "readwrite")
                .objectStore(storeName)
                .add(dbEntry); // contains "created" timestamp
```

And this is how I'm getting by guid (working):

```
 const request = database.transaction(storeName, "readwrite")
                .objectStore(storeName)
                .get(mediaId);
```

I have created the index here:

```
          request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
                const db = event.target.result;
                if (db.objectStoreNames.contains(storeName)) {
                    db.deleteObjectStore(storeName);
                }
                const objectStore = db.createObjectStore(storeName, { keyPath: keyPath });
                objectStore.createIndex("created", "created", { unique: false });
            };
```

How can the `getNewest` snippet be modified to support fetching by order of a date index?  I'll be using this to recursively delete the oldest items - so I can't just store a single "lastAdded" entry.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
// "created"
const latestMediaRequest = store.index(dateIndex).openCursor();
latestMediaRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
    const targetEntry = event.target.result.value;
}
```

Comment: `openCursor(null, 'prev')` to start from the last date